# Append a list to specific columns in a csv with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Hi Guys I can use some help if possible with Pandas: I have an existing csv that have the below structure:

```
column1  column2 column3 column4 
1         ww        1     Sam 
2         ss        2     Bill
                    3     Jack 

list = [[4,Jin],[5,Carl]]
```

I want to write into the csv under column3 and column4 to have the below results: `

```
column1 column2 column3 column4
 1       ww        1       Sam
 2       ss        2       Bill
                   3       Jack
                   4        Jin
                   5       Carl
```

Any help in this? I know pandas read through rows yet how this can be done?

Comment: Solution for this is as below:

Answer (score 1):

#### *The data* : fixed-width formatted

Your table needs to be read as it is `a table of fixed-width formatted lines`.
Thus using [`pandas.read_fwf`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html#pandas-read-fwf).

```
import pandas as pd 

pdcsv = pd.read_csv(inputcsv)
# reads
# column1  column2 column3 column4 
#  1         ww       1     Sam 
#  2         ss       2     Bill
#                     3     Jack
```

#### Appending Data

1. Create a `DataFrame` for the rows to append, using only the desired `columns 3` and `4`:

```
lst = [[4,'Jin'],[5,'Carl']]
newrows = pd.DataFrame(lst, columns=pdcsv.columns[2:])
# column3 column4 
#    4    Jin
#    5    Carl
```

2. Use `append`. Use `ignore_index=True` to reset old indexes.

```
pdcsv = pdcsv.append(newrows, ignore_index=True)
pdcsv 
#   column1 column2  column3 column4
# 0       1      ww        1     Sam
# 1       2      ss        2    Bill
# 2    None    None        3    Jack
# 3    None    None        4     Jin
# 4    None    None        5    Carl
```

Or use `pd.concat` like `pdcsv = pd.concat([pdcsv, newrows], ignore_index=True)`

#### Save

Using `.to_csv()`. Use `index=False` to not write a column for indexes.

```
pdcsv.to_csv('path\to\newfile.csv', index=False)
```

*Creates real csv file (not fwf)*

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pd.DataFrame.append`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) for this:

```
#   column1 column2  column3 column4
# 0       1      ww        1     Sam
# 1       2      ss        2    Bill
# 2    None    None        3    Jack

lst = [[4, 'Jin'], [5, 'Carl']]

app = pd.DataFrame([[None, None, x[0], x[1]] for x in lst],
                   columns=['column'+str(i) for i in range(1, 5)])

df = df.append(app, ignore_index=True)

#   column1 column2  column3 column4
# 0       1      ww        1     Sam
# 1       2      ss        2    Bill
# 2    None    None        3    Jack
# 3    None    None        4     Jin
# 4    None    None        5    Carl
```

Answer (score -1):

```
matrix = pd.read_csv(survey_dictionary)#, encoding="UTF-8")
fistElem = None
nullVector = matrix['column3'].isnull()
incr = 0
for isNull in nullVector:
    if isNull == True:
        fistElem = incr
        break
    incr = incr + 1
for source in list:
    if source[0] != fistElem:
        matrix.at[fistElem,'column3'] = source[0]
        matrix.at[fistElem,'column4'] = source[1]
matrix.to_csv(survey_dictionary, index =False, encoding='utf-8-sig')
```